# What is the difference between @Field and @Query in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

In some POST requests, I don't know when to use @Field with FormUrlEncoded and when to use @Query

For Example:

```
@POST("list-products-for-sale")
        Call<ListAllProductsResponse> getNewProducts(@HeaderMap Map<String, 
        String> headers,@Query("lastProductId") String lastProductId);
```

When I tried to use @Field here it was not responding properly and when I switched it to @Query it's working great.
I want to know why @Field isn't working while Query can work perfectly and I did tested in POSTMAN where I sent the data as a formurlencoded and it's giving me  the results fin.
**EDIT**
BTW I'm passing Content-Type:application/json, Accept: application/json with an Authorization key

Comment: A field manipulates the body of the request while a query is appended to the url

Comment: @Pratik Butani AndroidDev Thanks for the reference. Got to know the difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`@Field` is used to send `@FormUrlEncoded` request in `Retrofit` which hides your parameter and not attach with `url` to provide security.Used for `POST` request.

`@Query` parameter appended to the URL.

If you are using `@Field` request than it will hides your parameter and not append with the url.

If you are using `@Query` request than all your parameter is append to your request and visible to users.

Depend on your api request you have to use one of above annotation. If the api request accept the `@FormUrlEncoded` data than use `@Field` or if they want to attached it with url than use `@Query`.

You can get more information from below link :

1) https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html

2) https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html